# Missing $ inserted in tabular

Tags: tables

having trouble and cannot figure out how to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the LateX code that's causing the issue, not a screenshot of the code. Incidentally, how is the `C` column type defined? And, please also tell us a bit more about the platform you appear to be using.

Comment: I would guess `C` is defined as `>{$}c<{$}` and you therefore need to remove all the `$` in the first row. Unrelated but `\[\\\\ `  must be generatig warnings, remove `\\\\ `